# Using multiprocessing to find distances between points in array

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've been trying to speed up a practice project using python's multiprocessing library. In the project I have 2 arrays, points and weights, full of x, y coordinates. I'm trying to find the distance between each weight coordinate and point. When I run the program with multiprocessing, the program uses all the computers ram and CPU, and when looking at task manager, up to 20 instances of python are running. I know the program works because it works without multiprocessing but takes around 20 seconds to complete.

Here is the code, and at the bottom is the programming running with Pool.map and Process from the multiprocessing library.

```
import math
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

screenSize = 1000000

pointsLength = 2000
weightLength = 20000

weightBuffer = screenSize/weightLength
pointBuffer = screenSize/pointsLength

points = []
weights = []
weightPoints = []

counter = 0

for i in range(pointsLength):
    for j in range(pointsLength):
        points.append([random.randint(j * pointBuffer, j * pointBuffer * 2), 
        random.randint(i * pointBuffer, i * pointBuffer * 2)])


for i in range(pointsLength):
    for j in range(pointsLength):
        weightPoints.append([j * weightBuffer, i * weightBuffer])
        weights.append(0)


def FindDistance(i):
    row = math.floor((i / weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
    col = math.floor((i % weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
    points1d = (pointsLength * row) + col

    dist = math.dist(points[points1d], weightPoints[i])

    weights[i] = dist

# With Multiprocessing Pool
# sumthing = []
# for i in range(len(weights)):
#     sumthing.append(i)

# with mp.Pool(4) as p:
#     p.map(FindDistance, sumthing)


# With Multiproessing Process
processes = []
for i in range(len(weights)):
    p = mp.Process(target=FindDistance, args=[i])
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
    process.join()


# Without Multiprocessing
# for i in range(len(weights)):
#     FindDistance(i)

#     counter += 1

#     if (counter % 25000 == 0):
#         print(counter / 25000)
```

If anyone knows how I could get multiprocessing to work, where the program would use the 8 cores on my computer without crashing the program because of ram or cpu limitations.

Comment: ***How*** is the current program not working?

Comment: When I run the program, it freezes up because all the ram and cpu power is being used up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not doing multiprocessing correctly. Specifically your code is missing the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. This is fixed in the code below which uses `multiprocessing.Pool` (which I think would be the best and easiest way to do what you want). It still takes a number of seconds to execute, but it doesn't overwhelm memory and the CPUs.

Information about needing the `if __name__ == '__main__':` is buried in the **Safe importing of main module** subsection of [**The *`spawn`* and *`forkserver`* start methods**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) section of the `multiprocessing` module's documentation.

```
import math
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

screenSize = 1000000

pointsLength = 2000
weightLength = 20000

weightBuffer = screenSize/weightLength
pointBuffer = screenSize/pointsLength

points = []
weights = []
weightPoints = []

counter = 0

for i in range(pointsLength):
    for j in range(pointsLength):
        points.append([random.randint(j * pointBuffer, j * pointBuffer * 2),
        random.randint(i * pointBuffer, i * pointBuffer * 2)])


for i in range(pointsLength):
    for j in range(pointsLength):
        weightPoints.append([j * weightBuffer, i * weightBuffer])
        weights.append(0)


def FindDistance(i):
    row = math.floor((i / weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
    col = math.floor((i % weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
    points1d = (pointsLength * row) + col

    dist = math.dist(points[points1d], weightPoints[i])

    weights[i] = dist


if __name__ == '__main__':  # ADDED

    # With Multiprocessing Pool
    sumthing = []
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        sumthing.append(i)

    with mp.Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(FindDistance, sumthing)
```

Comment: I tried using your code, and entered the values 100000, 1000, 5000 for screenSize, pointsLength, weightLength. I ran the code using the multiprocessing code you provided and without. With the multiprocessing code the program took 104 seconds to complete and only 48 seconds without. I'm not sure why this is, taskbar shows similar ram and cpu usage, other than the multiprocessing one taking up multiple python instance. Is there still an error in the code, or is this problem not one that multiprocessing can solve.

Comment: There should be up to 5 instances of Python running concurrently. I'm not surprised it takes longer. Currently the code in my answer is just your own modified enough to prevent the program from freezing up, however it's *very* inefficient and not producing usable results due to the way it works with respect to multiprocessing — namely each process runs in its own memory space, so there's no shared global memory they can all access. This means each subprocess creates (and initializes) its own separate `points`, `weights`, and `weightPoints` lists. I'll look at things more tomorrow morning.

Comment: The speed of what's being done can't be improved via Python's `multiprocessing` module — there's just too much overhead involved. The reasons there's so much are because a separate OS-level process has to be created to run an almost trivial function one time to compute a single value in a shared list. On top of that, the function uses a couple of values from two other very large shared lists to calculate the value, and those must either must be recreated inside *each* subprocess or shared among them all, both of which entail a huge amount of overhead.

Comment: P.S. You might be able to speed things up by making the `FindDistance()` function do more than calculate a single value when it's called, so it wouldn't need to be called as often — which would reduce at least some the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the length of weights(2000 as per your code) and spawning a new process for every iteration, which means 2000 processes.
No wonder the CPU and RAM are full.

What you need to do is chunk the weights array into 8 smaller arrays, ideally of equal length. Change the FindDistance function to take an array as a parameter. This parameter will be the smaller chunked array.

```
def FindDistance(i_arr):
    for i in i_arr:
        row = math.floor((i / weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
        col = math.floor((i % weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
        points1d = (pointsLength * row) + col

        dist = math.dist(points[points1d], weightPoints[i])

        weights[i] = dist

def chunking(weights):
    # initialise array of empty arrays with Length equal to number of processors
    smaller_chunks = [ [] i for i in range(8) ]
    for index,item in enumerate(weights):
        index_to_push = index % 8
        smaller_chunks[index_to_push].append(item)

    return smaller_chunks
processes = []
chunks = chunking(weights)
for i in range(len(chunks)):
    p = mp.Process(target=FindDistance, args=[i])
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you are looping over the length of `weights`. which from your code

```
for i in range(pointsLength): #pointsLength is 2000
    for j in range(pointsLength):
        weightPoints.append([j * weightBuffer, i * weightBuffer])
        weights.append(0)
```

is 2000*2000 = 40,000

So you're trying to create 40,000 new processes all at once leading your system to crash.
What you can do instead is break down your list of `weights` into `n` smaller arrays and use that to just create `n` new processes

We can split the array using the numpy function `numpy.array_split`.
Now update the `FindDistance` function to accept the whole new array as an input.

```
def FindDistance(subarr):
    for i in subarr:
        row = math.floor((i / weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
        col = math.floor((i % weightLength) / (weightLength / pointsLength))
        points1d = (pointsLength * row) + col

        dist = math.dist(points[points1d], weightPoints[i])

        weights[i] = dist
```

and finally create `n` process with the new arguments

```
subarrays = np.array_split(weights, n)
processes = []
for subarr in subarrays:
    p = mp.Process(target=FindDistance, args=[subarr])
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```